# Using break statement in switch

Tags: switch-statement, swift, break

Following is the given example for using break statements in switch:

```
let numberSymbol: Character = "三"  // Simplified Chinese for the number 3
var possibleIntegerValue: Int?
switch numberSymbol {
case "1", "١", "一", "๑":
    possibleIntegerValue = 1
case "2", "٢", "二", "๒":
    possibleIntegerValue = 2
case "3", "٣", "三", "๓":
    possibleIntegerValue = 3
case "4", "٤", "四", "๔":
    possibleIntegerValue = 4
default:
    break
}
if let integerValue = possibleIntegerValue {
    println("The integer value of \(numberSymbol) is \(integerValue).")
} else {
    println("An integer value could not be found for \(numberSymbol).")
}
```

The `possibleIntegerValue` is `optional Int`, so I really don't find this as a better example of using breaks in switch. Instead of break, even `possibleIntegerValue = nil` also works.

```
let numberSymbol: Character = "三"  // Simplified Chinese for the number 3
var possibleIntegerValue: Int?
switch numberSymbol {
case "1", "١", "一", "๑":
    possibleIntegerValue = 1
case "2", "٢", "二", "๒":
    possibleIntegerValue = 2
case "3", "٣", "三", "๓":
    possibleIntegerValue = 3
case "4", "٤", "四", "๔":
    possibleIntegerValue = 4
default:
    possibleIntegerValue = nil
}
if let integerValue = possibleIntegerValue {
    println("The integer value of \(numberSymbol) is \(integerValue).")
} else {
    println("An integer value could not be found for \(numberSymbol).")
}
```

So in this case `break` is not required at all. Can anyone give me a proper example of using breaks in switch, where I purposely have to ignore some cases?

The book says:

> This behavior can be used to match and ignore one or more cases in a
>   switch statement. Because Swift’s switch statement is exhaustive and
>   does not allow empty cases, it is sometimes necessary to deliberately
>   match and ignore a case in order to make your intentions explicit. You
>   do this by writing the break statement as the entire body of the case
>   you want to ignore. When that case is matched by the switch statement,
>   the break statement inside the case ends the switch statement’s
>   execution immediately.

Comment: There is a great section on this in the Swift programming guide iBook

Comment: @NateCook Probably because this is quite fundamental to the language and emphasized heavily in all related session videos and documentation

Comment: Switches are emphasized heavily, but the break statement behavior is fairly non-standard compared to switch/break in most other languages. I think it's fair.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The `break` statement inside a `switch` can be used when you don't need a case to have any actual functionality, but want to include it to make your logic easier or clearer. Suppose for example you want to use a `switch` statement to determine if a given year is a leap year or not. (This is a bit of a contrived example.)

```
func isLeapYear(year: Int) -> Bool {
    switch (year) {
    case let x where (x % 100) == 0 && (x % 400) != 0:
        break
    case let x where (x % 4) == 0:
        return true
    default:
        break
    }

    return false
}

isLeapYear(2014)    // false
isLeapYear(2000)    // true
isLeapYear(1900)    // false
```

The first case of the `switch` statement inside `isLeapYear` lets you trap the cases where the year is both divisible by 100 and not divisible by 400, since those are sort of the exceptional non-leap years. The `break` statement in that case means "do nothing".

Comment: this code makes better sense than default one given by Apple. Thank you! (though if-else would be much better for this ;-)

Comment: Parantheses around the switch is not needed. Thus `switch year {` is enough.